# SSO Active Directory and Cloud User Mapping

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a rather weird situation. We have a .Net Application with it's own user management. The backend is running on a remote location and is multi-tenant capable. So each tenant has its own user pool.

Our Frontend is actually a Electron Client which is installed by our customers and can connect to our backend.

A lot of customers are asking for a SSO solution with their active directory (maybe even LDAP). I would like to create a native user in our user management and "connect"/map it to a active directory user.

How can I replace the username/password login with data that I receive once a AD login is being done in our electron client ? Ofc this needs to be rather secure.

Regards !